# How do I remove consecutive duplicates from a list?

Tags: python, duplicates

How do I remove consecutive duplicates from a list like this in python?

```
lst = [1,2,2,4,4,4,4,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5]
```

Having a unique list or set wouldn't solve the problem as there are some repeated values like 1,...,1 in the previous list.

I want the result to be like this:

```
newlst = [1,2,4,1,3,5]
```

Would you also please consider the case when I have a list like this 
 `[4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]` 
and I want the result to be `[4,2,3,3]` 
rather than `[4,2,3]` .

Comment: What do you mean by collapse?

Comment: look at `itertools.groupby`

Comment: Are you asking for a tool or an implementation? If you wanted to write it yourself, you could iterate through and keep any element that doesn't match the element before it.

Comment: `map(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.groupby(lst))`

Comment: is sorting order of any importance?

Comment: @neverendingqs I updated the question to explain it .

Comment: Yes order is important .

Comment: @ozgur Using this method he does not get a list. Converting this into a list will result in lower efficiency.

Comment: @Bharel `map` returns list in Python 2. Btw, returning a generator *(map returns a generator in Python 3)* is much more memory efficient in almost all cases than returning a list.

Comment: @ozgur he wanted a list, not a generator. If he needs to pass twice over the data, a generator will not suffice.

Comment: @Bharel it returns a list in Python 2. You are just making assumptions. He might need that to iterate through just once too. Thus, it is good to show such solution that produces a lazy iterator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is your solution.

```
newlst = [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst)]
```

---

If you wish to group and limit the group size by the item's value, meaning 8 4's will be [4,4], and 9 3's will be [3,3,3] here are 2 options that does it:

```
import itertools

def special_groupby(iterable):
    last_element = 0
    count = 0
    state = False
    def key_func(x):
        nonlocal last_element
        nonlocal count
        nonlocal state
        if last_element != x or x >= count:
            last_element = x
            count = 1
            state = not state
        else:
            count += 1
        return state
    return [next(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(iterable, key=key_func)]

special_groupby(lst)
```

OR

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

newlst = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(next(zip(*grouper(g, k))) for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst)))
```

Choose whichever you deem appropriate. Both methods are for numbers > 0.

Comment: It works very well, but with a list like this [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], I want the result to be [4,2,3,3] rather than [4,2,3]. can you guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: @ahmedmar Why would there be `[4,2,3,3]`? `[4,2,3]` is the correct output in this case. You wanted to remove duplicates, and there is nothing in between.

Comment: Is there a way to specify a limit to itertools to group a list by it . i.e. I want every 3,3,3 to be 3 and every 4,4,4,4 to be 4 ?

Comment: Yes you helped me a lot with removing duplicates. I just want a more specific solution to my case if possible. Any idea how could I do it ?

Comment: Another example, suppose a list [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3] if i specified itertool to collect every two dublicate items I will get [2,2,3,3].

Comment: Is there a reason not to simply use `newlst = [item[0] for item in itertools.groupby(lst)]`?

Comment: @jacob it is not his desired result

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the "Would you also please..." -section.

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b' , 'a', 'f', 'c', 'a','a']
temp_list = []


for item in list1:   
   if len(temp_list) == 0:
      temp_list.append(item)

   elif len(temp_list) > 0:
      if  temp_list[-1] != item:
          temp_list.append(item)

print(temp_list)
```

1. Fetch each item from the main list(list1).
2. If the 'temp_list' is empty add that item.
3. If not , check whether the last item in the temp_list is
   not same as the item we fetched from 'list1'.
4. if items are different append into temp_list.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `itertools` method @MaxU suggested, a possible code implementation is:

```
import itertools as it

lst=[1,2,2,4,4,4,4,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5]

unique_lst = [i[0] for i in it.groupby(lst)]

print(unique_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want something like this.

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2]
prev_value = None
for number in lst[:]: # the : means we're slicing it, making a copy in other words
    if number == prev_value:
        lst.remove(number)
    else:
        prev_value = number
```

So, we're going through the list, and if it's the same as the previous number, we remove it from the list, otherwise, we update the previous number.

There may be a more succinct way, but this is the way that looked most apparent to me.

HTH.

Comment: Probably better to construct new list, as removing items from a list in a for loop can cause problems

Comment: We do. We're iterating over a sliced copy of the list, not the original list. So no danger of falling over ourselves with deleting while we're iterating.

Comment: I missed that.. sorry!

Comment: No worries - it's bitten me before :)

Comment: Even with operation on a copy, this won't work correctly if the duplicated value occurred more than once place in the list. Try it on `[3, 2, 3, 3]`, for example. The issue is that `list.remove(3)` does not remove the duplicated `3` from the end, but rather than lone `3` from the start. `list.remove` is also very slow (each removal requires `O(N)` time).

Comment: Really? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
newlist=[]    
prev=lst[0]
newlist.append(prev)
    for each in lst[:1]: #to skip 1st lst[0]
        if(each!=prev):
            newlist.append(each)  
         prev=each
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
st = ['']
[st.append(a) for a in [1,2,2,4,4,4,4,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5] if a != st[-1]]
print(st[1:])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the next element always is not equal to item. If so append.

```
lst = [1,2,2,4,4,4,4,1,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5]

new_item = lst[0]
new_list = [lst[0]]
for l in lst:
   if new_item != l:
     new_list.append(l)
     new_item = l

print new_list
print lst
```